# Taking user-input into switch statements inside overloaded method

Tags: java, switch-statement, overloading, user-input

Here's what's required:

Two non-static overloaded methods which will return the movie run dates, one based upon the movies main actor and one based upon the start time , use a 24 hour clock as an int.  Use the switch statement to hardcode 4 different options

I just don't know how to take the user input and apply it to the overloaded methods in order to return the right data. Here's what I have so far

```
public class MovieTicket
{
   private String actorName;
   private int startTime;


public void setActorName(String actorName)
{
    this.actorName = actorName;
}

public void setStartTime(int startTime)
{
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

public String getActorName()
{
    return actorName;
}

public int getStartTime()
{
    return startTime;
}

public String movieTime(String runDate)
{
    switch (getActorName())
    {
        case "Jack Black":
            runDate = "0800";
        case "Jon Bon":
            runDate = "1100";
        case "Jan Ban":
            runDate = "1300";
        case "Jim Bim":
            runDate = "1600";
        default:
            runDate = "Please enter one of the following actors: Jack Black, Jon Bon, Jan Ban, or Jim Bim";
    }
    return runDate;
}

public int movieTime(int runDate)
{
    switch (getStartTime())
    {
        case 600:
            runDate= 1000;
        case 900:
            runDate = 1200;
        case 1400:
            runDate = 1700;
        case 1800:
            runDate = 2000;
    }
    return runDate;
}
```

I'm trying to access this in a separate class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MovieTicketTestHarness
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    MovieTicket mt1 = new MovieTicket();
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Please Enter a Main Actor: ");
    String setActorName = userInput.nextLine();
    mt1.setActorName(setActorName);
    
    System.out.println //calling method movieTime here (somehow)
}
```

}

Comment: What is stopping you from writing `System.out.println(mt1.movieTime(setActorTime));`?  Aside from that, `runDate` is not used actually as an argument -- likely it has been provided just for overriding. Also, `switch` statements are incorrect - they are written using syntax below Java 12+, therefore, `break` should be used in each `case`; currently the latest/default value is assigned to `runDate`

Comment: Thanks for the info! Pretty new to this. I was unsure if I needed break statements or not so I added them. Trying to print this : System.out.println(mt1.movieTime(getActorName()));

gives an error stating the method is undeclared. Not sure how I should set up my overriden methods